# Невозможно изменить содержимое переменной в каждом проходе цикла

Tags: python, массивы, list, математика

У меня есть проблема, связанная с алгоритмическим скриптом. У меня есть массив, в котором есть x, в котором лежит какое-то уравнение, я меняю их на другую переменную и вроде бы все хорошо, но когда мне попадаются однотипные числа, я не могу просто продолжить расчет. Помоги мне, пожалуйста.

```
def func():
    try:
        a = int(input('Введите диапазон с(пример: 0):'))
        b = int(input('Введите диапазон до (пример: 100):'))
        x = b // 2
        mas = [x]
        for i in range(b):
            first_q = input(f'Ваше число больше {format(*mas)}? (если это ваше угаданное число  то напишите(ты угадал!):')
            if first_q == 'Да' or first_q == 'да':
                a = x
                x_1 = x + (b - x) // 2 #+ random.randint(0,1)
                mas.append(x_1)
                mas.pop(0)
                print(x_1)
            elif first_q == 'Нет' or first_q == 'нет':
                b = x
                x_1 = x // 2
                mas.append(x_1)
                mas.pop(0)
                a = x_1
                print(x_1)
            elif first_q == 'ты угадал':
                print('ООО,отлично спасибо большое за игру!!')
                break
            else:
                break
    except ValueError as v:
        print(f'Привет у тебя ошибка с int,пожалуйста проверь что ты ввел все правильно! Вот ошибка:{v}')


func()
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно..

Comment: try здесь не к месту, его нужно исспользовать лишь для одной строки типа
```
try:
  x=int(input...)
except...
```

Comment: уже поменял((((